# is blood anaerobic?

Tags: hematology

I was wondering if anyone knows whether there is free molecular oxygen in the blood?

My reasoning would be that oxygen is too reactive to be left alone in the blood, that's why it is transported in a little metal box called hemoglobin. Because of this, blood serum ought to be anaerobic(I know that some immune cells produce reactive oxygen species to kill off microorganisms, but let's ignore this for now). Is this correct?

for those who downvoted the question try to find the answer by googling it. All it shows is anaerobic blood culture of bacteria.

Who said this is homework? I'm probably three times as old as you are and you go flagging this as homework? really? get a life.

Answer (score 2):

Oxygen presumably does dissolve in blood.  At least nitrogen does (as any scuba diver could tell you), and I don't know why oxygen should be different.  And a quick search shows it does dissolve in blood, but only about 2% of the amount carried by red blood cells: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK54103/